# Access row of array that has multiple values

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have an array where the certificate columns has rows that contain multiple values. The ... indicates there are more than one value there.

For example, looking at the row for "mo.portalapp1.doris..." This is what I mean by multiple values being there.

[image]

[image]

I need to expand that row to see all four values as well as keep the expiration date which is obviously the same for all four. They are just essentially grouped together and need to un-group them almost. I tried using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Certificate` and that does expand and show all the results, but then I lose the 'ExpirationDate' column. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you,

Comment: loop over each object then loop over each value in the `Certificate` property then create each new object to get a flatten object as result.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon How do I make sure the expirationdate stay consistent and is added to the row

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can you provide example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`, but because the expanded value is a flat string (as opposed to a custom object with multiple properties), you need a bit more work to turn each value back into a `Certificate` property:

```
$array = $array |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Certificate -ExpandProperty Certificate |Select-Object @{Name='Certificate';Expression={"$_"}},* -ExcludeProperty Length
```

This might look a bit counter-intuitive, but the first `Select-Object` expands the string values from the `Certificate` property, and then attaches all remaining properties to the resulting values - we now have a list of strings with ETS properties attached to it.

The second `Select-Object` then creates a new object copying all the attached properties except for `String.Length` (ie. all the properties we copied from the original object), and re-attaches a `Certificate` property that contains the value of the string itself.

Let's test it on some dummy data:

```
$array = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Certificate = @('cert1', 'cert2', 'cert3')
    ExpirationDate = '2022-01-05'
    Email = 'user@domain'
    Site = 'KY'
  }
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Certificate = @('cert4', 'cert5')
    ExpirationDate = '2022-01-10'
    Email = 'user@domain'
    Site = 'KY'
  }
)

$array |Format-Table

$array = $array |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Certificate -ExpandProperty Certificate |Select-Object @{Name='Certificate';Expression={"$_"}},* -ExcludeProperty Length

$array |Format-Table
```

Which shows the desired transformation:

```
Certificate           ExpirationDate Email       Site
-----------           -------------- -----       ----
{cert1, cert2, cert3} 2022-01-05     user@domain KY
{cert4, cert5}        2022-01-10     user@domain KY



Certificate ExpirationDate Email       Site
----------- -------------- -----       ----
cert1       2022-01-05     user@domain KY
cert2       2022-01-05     user@domain KY
cert3       2022-01-05     user@domain KY
cert4       2022-01-10     user@domain KY
cert5       2022-01-10     user@domain KY
```

Comment: This didn't work. They are still contained in there

Comment: What is still contained in what? :)

Comment: @jssteele89 Perhaps the problem is that `Certificate` doesn't contain an array - perhaps it's value is just a single multi-line string? Can you show how you obtained/created the data stored in `$array` in the first place?